How do I include a column in the results of an aggregated query if the column should not be aggregated?
The scenario is where employees worked in different facilties and I need to identify their first start date across all facilities and also include the name of that facility.
I have accomplished this with a CTE that first identifies the first date, and then joins that CTE to the original dataset, but it is clumsy and I'm hoping there is a cleaner method.
Here is some test code to illustrate:
drop table tempreporttable

Select * into TempReportTable from
(select 1 as TID,'Employee1' as Employee, 'FacilityA' as Facility, '1/1/2020' as StartDate union all
select 2, 'Employee1','FacilityB', '1/1/2021' union all
select 3, 'Employee2','FacilityA', '1/1/2019' union all
select 4, 'Employee3','FacilityB', '1/1/2018') temp

;with FirstDate as
(select Employee, min(StartDate) FirstDate from TempReportTable group by employee)

select t.*
from TempReportTable t
join FirstDate fd on t.Employee = fd.Employee and t.StartDate = fd.FirstDate

